# WEB Service SOAP instanciar classe

Tags: java, web-service, soap, soapclient

Boa tarde pessoal , estou tentando instanciar uma classe de um WS SOAP porem esta dando o seguinte erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

segue abaixo o codigo do meu method :

```
  public void consultaOperadoresSafra(){
    CapturaPropostas capturaPropostas = new CapturaPropostas();
    ICapturaPropostas iCapturaPropostas = capturaPropostas.getBasicHttpBindingICapturaPropostas();
    DadosBasicosSafra basicosSafra = iCapturaPropostas.dadosSafra("1DFFA600E6489D3700A39CE2E5BEFD01");
    System.out.println(basicosSafra);
}
```

abaixo o codigo do meu WS SOAP:

```
package org.tempuri;
```

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;
import javax.xml.ws.WebEndpoint;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceClient;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature;

@WebServiceClient(
    name = "CapturaPropostas",
    targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/",
    wsdlLocation = "https://fei-h.safrafinanceira.com.br/CapturaPropostas.svc?wsdl"
)
public class CapturaPropostas extends Service {
    private static final URL CAPTURAPROPOSTAS_WSDL_LOCATION;
    private static final WebServiceException CAPTURAPROPOSTAS_EXCEPTION;
    private static final QName CAPTURAPROPOSTAS_QNAME = new QName("http://tempuri.org/", "CapturaPropostas");

```
public CapturaPropostas() {
    super(__getWsdlLocation(), CAPTURAPROPOSTAS_QNAME);
}

public CapturaPropostas(WebServiceFeature... features) {
    super(__getWsdlLocation(), CAPTURAPROPOSTAS_QNAME, features);
}

public CapturaPropostas(URL wsdlLocation) {
    super(wsdlLocation, CAPTURAPROPOSTAS_QNAME);
}

public CapturaPropostas(URL wsdlLocation, WebServiceFeature... features) {
    super(wsdlLocation, CAPTURAPROPOSTAS_QNAME, features);
}

public CapturaPropostas(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName) {
    super(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
}

public CapturaPropostas(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName, WebServiceFeature... features) {
    super(wsdlLocation, serviceName, features);
}

@WebEndpoint(
    name = "BasicHttpBinding_ICapturaPropostas"
)
public ICapturaPropostas getBasicHttpBindingICapturaPropostas() {
    return (ICapturaPropostas)super.getPort(new QName("http://tempuri.org/", "BasicHttpBinding_ICapturaPropostas"), ICapturaPropostas.class);
}

@WebEndpoint(
    name = "BasicHttpBinding_ICapturaPropostas"
)
public ICapturaPropostas getBasicHttpBindingICapturaPropostas(WebServiceFeature... features) {
    return (ICapturaPropostas)super.getPort(new QName("http://tempuri.org/", "BasicHttpBinding_ICapturaPropostas"), ICapturaPropostas.class, features);
}

private static URL __getWsdlLocation() {
    if (CAPTURAPROPOSTAS_EXCEPTION != null) {
        throw CAPTURAPROPOSTAS_EXCEPTION;
    } else {
        return CAPTURAPROPOSTAS_WSDL_LOCATION;
    }
}

static {
    URL url = null;
    WebServiceException e = null;

    try {
        url = new URL("https://fei-h.safrafinanceira.com.br/CapturaPropostas.svc?wsdl");
    } catch (MalformedURLException var3) {
        e = new WebServiceException(var3);
    }

    CAPTURAPROPOSTAS_WSDL_LOCATION = url;
    CAPTURAPROPOSTAS_EXCEPTION = e;
}
```

}

**ALGUEM PODE ME DAR UM HELP POR FAVOR NÃO ESTOU CONSEGUIND OFAZER ESTE METODO EXECUTAR**.

Comment: Pelo visto seu problema tá na URL onde você deve consumir!

Comment: Boa tarde @CarlosMesquitaAguiar o URL  esta conectando normal fiz o teste https://fei-h.safrafinanceira.com.br/CapturaPropostas.svc?wsdl

navegador: GOOGLE CHROME

Answer (score 0):

Faça um teste gerando o cliente do seu wsdl -> https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/education/web/t320/Generating_a_client_from_WSDL.pdf

Segue passo a passo... Se funcionar basta só pegar o código e jogar para sua aplicação.